# django copy selected data from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, django, celery

Can anybody help me. I want to know if there is a good solution to moving a large amount of data filtered from one table in an oracle db to another in a mysql db.
I know that you can run a query and loop over the results of it and insert it to the other database but the problem is that it may run out of memory and i'm looking for a good solution like running jobs or some asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) system (maybe without the T in your case)

Time ago I use [pygrametl](https://github.com/chrthomsen/pygrametl) and it managed the data surprisingly fast.

Another option is [django bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) (don't try to insert all data at once, split data into chunks)